# I need to regex replace a word in a URL and can't seem to figure it out

Tags: regex, regexp-replace

Google recently changed how business profiles are editing for multi-locations in their dashboard. The simple fix for now is to simply replace /dashboard/ in the URL with /edit/.

I'm trying to come up with a regex to do just that for a Chrome extension. The info below is what the extension is needing to make that happen.

Redirect: https://business.google.com/dashboard/l/01914880984880687972
to: https://business.google.com/edit/l/01914880984880687972

Thoughts?

Screenshot of the chrome extension
[image]

Tried a lot of combinations but regex apperantly isn't in the cards for me.

Answer (score 0):

If all you're looking for is a replacement of '/dashboard/' with '/edit/' and only for the business.google.com url, I would avoid REGEX and do a simple string replacement.

```js
const url = "https://business.google.com/dashboard/l/01914880984880687972";
url.replace('dashboard', 'edit'); 
console.log('New url: ', url);
// New url:  https://business.google.com/dashboard/l/01914880984880687972
```

For a chrome extension you could enable tab permissions by adding "tabs" to the "permissions" array in manifest.json, then grab the url of the active tab like so:

```js
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true}, tabs => {
    let url = tabs[0].url;
    // url.replace('dashboard', 'edit'); or anything else
    // window.replace(url) for redirection
});
```